# How to count records of particular id in spring boot and hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-boot, hql

I am working on a project using Spring boot and hibernate. I want to count records against an id in table. I can count all records of the table but unable to count records against a foreign key.

Here is my controller code

```
@RequestMapping("/rating/{id}")
@ResponseBody 
 public long getRatingInfo(@PathVariable("id") long id, HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws Exception {

long postobj = myDao.count();
return postobj;
}
```

Here i am passing an `id` in url but there is no method of `count` to pass this id to find records.

And here is my Dao Interface

```
@Transactional
public interface MyDaoInterface extends CrudRepository<Rating, Long>{
}
```

Comment: Do you want to count of `rating` for a given `id`?

Comment: Actually i have rating table in my db. In this table i have post_id, user_id and rating_points columns . post_id can be multiple and i want to count all rows of a given post_id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this to your DAO:

```
@Query(countByPostId)
Integer countByPostId(Long post_id);

final String countByPostId= "SELECT COUNT(ra) FROM Rating ra WHERE ra.post_id = ?1"
```

And call it likewise:

```
@RequestMapping("/rating/{id}")
@ResponseBody 
public long getRatingInfo(@PathVariable("id") long id, HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws Exception {

long postobj = myDao.countByPostId(id);
return postobj;
}
```

**EDIT**: the second question in the comments:

```
@Transactional
public interface MyDaoInterface extends CrudRepository<Rating, Long>{
   List<Rating> findByPostId(Long id);
}
```

and your caller:

```
@RequestMapping("/rating/{id}")
@ResponseBody 
public long getRatingInfo(@PathVariable("id") long id, HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws Exception {

 List<Rating> ratings = myDao.findByPostId(id);
 long postobj = ratings.size() //use this code where you effectively need the # of entires.

 return ratings;
}
```

Comment: I am running this query...  "select count(r.id),points from Rating r where r.postId=?1 group by points";   And i am using List as return type.. i am getting results but not getting column name in result

Comment: what should i do here can you tell me?

Comment: Try: `select count(r.id), r.points from Rating r where r.post_id=?1 group by r.points`

Comment: same result... not getting column names

Comment: i am unable to understand which column value is it

Comment: Usually in hibernate you expect an Entity-Annotated-Object or a Collection of it as a result. In your case the following would make sense: `List<Rating> findByPostId(Long id);` So you get all matching `rating` records. For the count you can use the List.size() method.

Comment: I added a `second question` comment.

Comment: getting same results :(

Comment: Could you open a new question? with the exact problem, what you expect and your stacktrace?

Comment: I have posted a new question here is the link..   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32310204/not-getting-column-names-in-the-result-of-hql-query

Comment: for this `@Query(value="SELECT a.tagid, a.tagName, count(*) FROM articletaglist a GROUP BY a.tagName" , nativeQuery=true)
 public List<TCategoryCount> findTagCount();`  im getting `No converter found capable of converting from type` ERROR

Answer (score 0):

```
@RequestMapping("/rating/{id}")
@ResponseBody 
public long getRatingInfo(@PathVariable("id") long id, HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws Exception {

 List<Rating> ratings = myDao.findByPostId(id);
 long postobj = ratings.size() //use this code where you effectively need the # of entires.

 return ratings;
}
```