# Not getting column names in the result of hql query

Tags: spring, hibernate, rest, spring-boot, hql

I am getting records from database table using hql query in spring boot. I am returning result in json object using @ResponseBody. I am getting only data but not getting column names so i am unable to understand which column containg which data.

Here is my **DAO**

```
@Transactional
public interface MyDaoInterface extends CrudRepository<Rating, Long>{

@Query(countByPostId)
List<Rating> countByPostId(Long post_id);

final String countByPostId= "select new netgloo.models.CountAndPoints(count(r.id), r.points)) from Rating r where r.postId = ?1 group by r.points";

}
```

Here is my **controller**

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/rating/{id}", produces="application/json")
  @ResponseBody 
  public List<Rating> getRatingInfo(@PathVariable("id") long id,    HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws Exception {

  List<Rating> postobj = myDao.countByPostId(id);
  return postobj;
  }
```

Getting data like

```
[
{
"count": 3,
"points": 1
},
{
"count": 2,
"points": 2
},
{
"count": 4,
"points": 3
}
]
```

But i want like

```
"result:"[
{
"count": 3,
"points": 1
},
{
"count": 2,
"points": 2
},
{
"count": 4,
"points": 3
}
]
```

New class **CountAndPoints**

```
package netgloo.models;

public class CountAndPoints {

private long count;

private long points;

public long getCount() {
    return count;
}

public void setCount(long count) {
    this.count = count;
}

public long getPoints() {
    return points;
}

public void setPoints(long points) {
    this.points = points;
}

}
```

**Exception**

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mainController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private netgloo.models.MyDaoInterface netgloo.controllers.MainController.myDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myDaoInterface': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List netgloo.models.MyDaoInterface.countByPostId(java.lang.Long)!
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1210)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:686)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:957)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:946)
at netgloo.Application.main(Application.java:25)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private netgloo.models.MyDaoInterface netgloo.controllers.MainController.myDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myDaoInterface': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List netgloo.models.MyDaoInterface.countByPostId(java.lang.Long)!
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:561)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
... 16 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myDaoInterface': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List netgloo.models.MyDaoInterface.countByPostId(java.lang.Long)!
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1120)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1044)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:942)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:533)
... 18 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List netgloo.models.MyDaoInterface.countByPostId(java.lang.Long)!
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.validateQuery(SimpleJpaQuery.java:92)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.<init>(SimpleJpaQuery.java:62)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryFactory.fromMethodWithQueryString(JpaQueryFactory.java:72)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryFactory.fromQueryAnnotation(JpaQueryFactory.java:53)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$DeclaredQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:135)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:203)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:72)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:349)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:187)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.initAndReturn(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:239)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:225)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:92)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1633)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1570)
... 28 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected end of subtree [select new netgloo.models.CountAndPoints(count(r.id), r.points)) from netgloo.models.Rating r where r.postId = ?1 group by r.points]
at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1750)
at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1677)
at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1683)
at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:331)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:344)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy63.createQuery(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.validateQuery(SimpleJpaQuery.java:86)
... 41 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected end of subtree [select new netgloo.models.CountAndPoints(count(r.id), r.points)) from netgloo.models.Rating r where r.postId = ?1 group by r.points]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:91)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter.throwQueryException(ErrorCounter.java:109)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:284)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:206)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:158)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:131)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:93)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:167)
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:301)
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:236)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1800)
at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:328)
... 48 more
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@Query(countByPostId)
List<Rating> countByPostId(Long post_id);

final String countByPostId= "select count(r.id), r.points from Rating r where r.postId=?1 group by r.points";
```

This doesn't make much sense. Your query does not return a list of Rating instances. It returns a list of Object arrays, where each array contains 2 elements: a count and a number of points.

The Rating class doesn't even have a field containing counts anyway.

You need some class that contains these two fields, and a query that returns instances of this class:

```
select new com.foo.bar.CountAndPoints(count(r.id), r.points) from Rating r where r.postId = ?1 group by r.points"
```

Comment: Thanx for your reply but getting this exception ...    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List netgloo.models.MyDaoInterface.countByPostId(java.lang.Long)!

Comment: If you want help with that, you'll have to edit your question, show the new query, show the class you defined, and show the complete stack trace of the exception.

Comment: do i need to create new class CountAndPoints?

Comment: You need a public constructor taking the count and the points as argument, since that's what the query is calling. And you have two parentheses instead of one after `r.points`

Comment: yes its working thanks..but can i give a name to list which is returning? because i am getting only variables names.

Comment: i mean i want json object name which is returned to client side.

Comment: Give a concrete example. Objects don't have names.

Comment: please check my edited question... my current output and which output i want

Comment: Your example is not valid JSON. But you just need to understand that the JSON structure is the same as the Java structure. A Java List of Objects with two properties count and points is serialized as a JSON array of objects with two fields count and points. If you want a JSON object with a single field named "result", of type array, then you need to return a Java Object with a single property named "result", of type List.

Comment: but in many examples i return class name as list name. Here too i am returning a list of typeList<Rating>

Comment: No. You return a `List<CountAndPoints>`. This will be serialized as an array. If you want an object containing an array, you'll have to return an object containing that list. It's as simpe as that.

Comment: then how can i change this to object?

Comment: As I said. Instead of returning a List<CountAndPoints> from your controller, return an object containing a property named result, which is of type List<CountAndPoints>. The structure of the Java object should match with the structure of the JSON you expect.

Comment: can you edit my controller please because i dont know much about that..so i am unable to understand

Comment: thank you very much its working and i also learnt from your code :)

Comment: If i need only 1 record from db then what will be used in hql query? In simple sql query we use LIMIT .

Comment: Here is the question for this problem..   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32390410/how-to-get-only-one-record-using-hql-in-spring-boot

Answer (score -1):

Spring generates the query for you in that case. Use this code instead:

```
@Transactional
public interface MyDaoInterface extends CrudRepository<Rating, Long>{
  List<Rating> findByPostId(Long post_id);
}
```

For a complete answer see JB Nizet's answer.